# Show combined size of multiple uploaded files

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, file-upload

I'm making an upload function with php, which works fine.
Only, because the maximum size in my php ini file is 32mb, I can't upload anything bigger than that. And that's fine with me.

**BUT**:
I want to prevent uploading when the **combined size** of all the files that are added to input-file, is over 32mb.

I found this script which alerts the file size after adding the files, which is a start:

```
$(function(){
    $('#file').change(function(){
        var file=this.files[0]
        alert(file.size||file.fileSize)
    })
})
```

But when testing I found out that it only returns the size of **one** file.
How can I alter this code to return the size of **all the files** that are added to the input field? Or is there another way to do this?

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Tutorial</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/tut.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<form action="tutorial.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!--<input type="file" name="myFile"><p>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    <br/><br/>-->
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" id="file"/><p>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="submit" />
</form>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP code:

```
$file_dest = "photos/orig/";
$thumb_dest = "photos/thumbs/";

if(!empty($_FILES['files']['name'][0])){

    $files = $_FILES['files'];

    $uploaded = array();
    $failed = array();

    $allowedExt = array('png', 'jpg', 'gif');

    foreach($files['name'] as $position => $file_name) {
        $file_tmp = $files['tmp_name'][$position];
        $file_size = $files['size'][$position];
        $file_error = $files['error'][$position];

        $file_ext = explode('.', $file_name);
        $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

        if(in_array($file_ext, $allowedExt)){

            if($file_error == 0){

                if($file_size <= 20000000){

                    $file_name_new = uniqid('', true)."_".$file_name;
                    $file_move = $file_dest.$file_name_new;

                    if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_move)){
                        $uploaded[$position] = $file_dest;

                    }else{
                        $failed[$position] = "[{$file_name}] failed to upload.";
                    }

                }else{
                    $failed[$position] = "[{$file_name}] is too large.";
                }

            }else{
                $failed[$position] = "[P$file_name}] errored with code {$file_error}";
            }

        }else{
            $failed[$position] = "[{$file_name}] file extension '{$file_ext}' is not allowed.";
        }
    }

    if(!empty($uploaded)){
        print_r($uploaded);
    }

    if(!empty($failed)){
        print_r($failed);
    }
}else{
    echo "No files were added.";
}
```

*Sidenote: The code's not finished yet, I still have to add security measures. Please ignore the lack thereof.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $('#file').change(function(){
        var combinedSize = 0;
        for(var i=0;i<this.files.length;i++) {
            combinedSize += (this.files[i].size||this.files[i].fileSize);
        }
        alert(combinedSize);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You'd do that by summing up the sizes

```
$(function(){
    $('#file').on('change', function(){
        var total = [].slice.call(this.files).map(function(x) {
            return x.size || x.fileSize;
        }).reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);

        if ( total > 33554432 ) {
            alert('Total size exceeds 32 mb');
        }

    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4AVQ5/1/)